# Are there any contemporary diaries about the Yugoslav Wars?

Tags: sources, the-balkans

I struggle to find any, I think about diary, as written by someone who was at the heart of the war, with some proper understanding of the things happening around him, like the "Berlin Diary" from William Shirer.

I really enjoyed Shirer's "Berlin Diary", an American foreign correspondent's experience in the first years of WW2, and his growing disillusionment through time, and I was hoping to find something similar for the Yugoslav wars; I'd like a book that looks at the situation on a wider scale, and also is factual - which might be a bit naive to search for in a highly intense war time.

I found [Sarajevo: A War Journal by Zlatko Dizdarevic](https://www.amazon.fr/dp/0880641495/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_IYmVFbTSA8659), [Zlata's Diary by Zlata Filipović](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlata%27s_Diary). Even [General Mladic kept a journal](https://www.france24.com/en/20100710-general-mladic-war-diary-srebrenica-serbia-bosnia-belgrade-karadzic-genocide).  My concern is that I don't think Zlata's Diary would look at the things at a wider scale, and Mladic's journal would say more about himself, than about the war, as I think it is highly biased because of him being a "warlord". I will certainly pick up Zlatko Dizdarevic's book, but I was searching for a more factual book - which might be a bit naive to search for in a highly intense war time.

Comment: What are the results of your search? At a quick internet search I find a few: [Sarajevo: A War Journal by Zlatko Dizdarevic](https://www.amazon.fr/dp/0880641495/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_IYmVFbTSA8659), [Zlata's Diary by Zlata Filipović](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlata%27s_Diary). Even [General Mladic kept a journal](https://www.france24.com/en/20100710-general-mladic-war-diary-srebrenica-serbia-bosnia-belgrade-karadzic-genocide).

Comment: @cipricus Thank you for your response; I found these too, but my concern is that I don't think Zlata's Diary would look at the things at a wider scale, and Mladic's journal would say more about himself, than about the war, as I think it is highly biased because of him being a "warlord". I will certainly pick up Zlatko Dizdarevic's book, but I was searching for a more factual book, which might be a bit naive to search for in a highly intense war time.

Comment: I don't think a wider view on a war can be found in a personal journal, with the exception of those kept by decision makers, no matter their political bias. A personal journal can bring a different knowledge, something that no history book can, a trace of a personal experience of war. - Probably many journals have not yet been published. A search in Serbian/Croatian would be helpful.

Comment: @cipricus I understand, I really enjoyed Shirer's "Berlin Diary", an American foreign correspondent's experience in the first years of WW2, and his growing disillusionment through time, and I was hoping to find something similar for the Yugoslaw wars. Anyway, thank you, for your comment!

Comment: I have tried a search in Serbian (the results would present a pro-Serbian position of course), found only 2: [The Journal of a war surgeon – dr Miodrag Lazic](https://nevendjenadija.wordpress.com/2020/04/15/the-journal-of-a-war-surgeon-dr-miodrag-lazic-pdf-srbian-and-english/), also in English, 
[Ratni dnevnik, Pale 1993-1995 by Jeni Ligtenberg](https://www.amazon.com/Ratni-dnevnik-Pale-1993-1995-Ligtenberg/dp/8673965640), just in Serbian.

Comment: @samivagyok - please move all of your comments into the main question.  Questions should stand alone without reference to comments. Comments are [barn cats](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3631/1401).

Comment: The titles I posted are not great books I fear. Maybe you shouldn't set my answer as definitive just yet. Anyway, you should re-activate (e.g. edit) the question over time so that you get newer answers with what you really want, a well-written Yugoslav war journal in English.

Comment: @cipricus why do you think the books you mentioned are not great?

Comment: I mean the ones beside what you yourself found, already in English, translated because they have some interest. Most of the others in Serbian might be modest as dimension and scope or even naively nationalistic. My suggestion is to keep your question in view by trying to edit it and add useful new info like new titles you already know (so that people don't post what you have already) and info about books of this kind that you read, for others to have a better idea on the topic. I am myself interested in this and I would like to know about what you'll find.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking for a war journal written by a good writer. I am not aware of one, and haven't read the ones listed below. I am posting them as the result of a quick search on the internet in English, Serbian and Croatian. I hope to find others in time, which I will post here.

Beside the ones in English mentioned in comment ( [Sarajevo: A War Journal by Zlatko Dizdarevic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0880641495), [Zlata's Diary by Zlata Filipović](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0140374639)) I have tried a search in Serbian and Croatian (the results seem all Serbian and some might present a pro-Serbian position close to propaganda).

[The Journal of a war surgeon – dr Miodrag Lazic](https://nevendjenadija.wordpress.com/2020/04/15/the-journal-of-a-war-surgeon-dr-miodrag-lazic-pdf-srbian-and-english/), in Sarajevo, also in English.

[Ratni dnevnik, Pale 1993-1995 by Jeni Ligtenberg](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8673965640), just in Serbian, the journal of a Dutch pharmacist that worked in a hospital in Pale.

Also in Serbian [War diary of a Sarajevo priest by Dragomir Ubiparipović](https://www.kupindo.com/Istorija/59319819_Ratni-dnevnik-sarajevskog-svestenika).